# Retrieving Media File's MetaData Pre MediaMetaDataRetriever (API 10)

Tags: android, metadata

I support from API level 8 in my application and would like to also be able to get a file's meta data in API levels 8 and 9 as well as 10 and above.

For above and including level 10 I am using `MediaMetadataRetriever` however I can't seem to find the alternative to use.

**My Question**

What should I use to retrieve a file's meta data in API levels pre-10?

A code example would also be very useful.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever](https://github.com/wseemann/FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever) (API 7+). It has the same interface as `MediaMetadataRetriever`:

```
import wseemann.media.FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever;

...

FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever mmr = new FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever();
mmr.setDataSource(mUri);
mmr.extractMetadata(FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_ALBUM);
mmr.extractMetadata(FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_ARTIST);
Bitmap b = mmr.getFrameAtTime(2000000, FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever.OPTION_CLOSEST); // frame at 2 seconds
byte [] artwork = mmr.getEmbeddedPicture();

mmr.release();
```

Comment: FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever now Support for API 12+ as of latest version to date of this comment i.e. v1.0.11